# Release event firing even when the mouse button is not released. WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, event-handling

I have a button whose `ClickMode` is initially set to "Press". The code for the event handler for this button is as follows:

```
Button button_clicked = sender as Button;
if (button_clicked.ClickMode == ClickMode.Press)
{
    button_clicked.ClickMode = ClickMode.Release;
    button_clicked.Content = "Pressed";
}

else if (button_clicked.ClickMode == ClickMode.Release)
{
    button_clicked.ClickMode = ClickMode.Press;
    button_clicked.Content = "Released";
}
```

This should set the content of the button to "Pressed" when the button is first clicked. The content should remain as "Pressed" until the button is released and it should be set as "Released" as soon as the button is released.

But, the actual behaviour is different. When you click the button, the content is set to "Pressed". Then if you hold it long enough (5-6 seconds, I guess), its content changes to "Released" **even if you don't release it and keep it pressed.**

Edit: I'm using "Multi-touch vista" to simulate multi-touch on the emulator. This behaviour is observed when I run the emulator with Multi-touch vista. When I don't use Multi-touch vista, it works fine. Any suggestions on how to get both working?

Please help me with this.
Thank you.

Comment: It turns out that I had installed "Multi touch vista" in order to simulate multi-touch on the emulator. http://michaelsync.net/2010/04/06/step-by-step-tutorial-installing-multi-touch-simulator-for-silverlight-phone-7

When I stopped using it, it started working for me. Any ideas on how I could use it with the multi-touch simulator?

Comment: Are you merely trying to change the content of the button while it is pressed? This is correctly handled with the VisualStateManager and the "MouseOver" VisualState.

Comment: @terphi - No, I'm not trying to just change the content of the buttons. This is just simplified code to highlight the problem. I got around this problem with a crude quick fix. Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conversation above indicates that this issue was actually a side effect from installing a multi-touch simulator.

*Answering here to get this off the unanswered list.*